# Error insertando en base de datos pgsql con proyecto laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, postgresql, undefined

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: no existe la columna «id»
>   LINE 1: ...ated_at") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) returning
>   "id" ^ (SQL: insert into "productos" ("cod_producto", "nom_producto",
>   "tipo_producto", "valor_producto", "cant_producto", "updated_at",
>   "created_at") values (2, aaaaaa, Tarjeta, 123, 12, 2019-03-21
>   22:04:49, 2019-03-21 22:04:49) returning "id")

`cod_producto` es la **primarykey** de mi tabla *`productos`*, pero cuando intento insertar mediante un formulario sencillo me retorna ese error, no sé porque no  cambio "id" a: "cod_producto", al momento de usar en la consola el comando: `php artisan migrate;` ya que lo modifique en el modelo y la migración.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, podrías agregar el código de la migración (como texto) a tu pregunta. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Tu llave primaria debe llamarse id

Comment: ¿y dónde está el código del modelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas utilizar una llave primaria distinta a id, debes especificarlo en el modelo de Laravel, con la propiedad primaryKey:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cod_producto';
```

En la documentación puedes ver más información: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: perdón que responda hasta ahora, el profe soluciono eso, pero estas en lo correcto, mil gracias